# Working on a Visual Studio project with VS 2012 and VS 2015

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2015, compatibility, projects-and-solutions

I am currently using VS 2012 as programming environment. Projects include C# Windows Forms, WCF, WPF and ASP.Net applications. The question now is, if I can use both VS 2012 and VS 2015 to work on these projects. This is because a new programmer is joining the team and we would like to start using VS 2015. 
I have already tried it with a simple Windows Forms application and did not run into any problems (opened it in VS 2015, changed something, compiled and ran it; then switched back to VS 2012 and compiled/ran it again). Should this theoretically work for complex ASP.Net and WPF applications as well?
I am aware that the target .Net framework can cause problems if we use a higher version that is not supported in VS 2012, but apart from that, anything else we should consider?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh266747.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After almost two weeks of working with both VS 2012 and 2015 on different projects I can confirm that this is working fine. What I did was to work with VS 2012 on the one day, then switch to VS 2015 on the next day, then back to 2012, and so on. I have done this with projects that involve the following project types: Windows Forms application, ASP.Net Web Forms application, WCF services. I did not run into a single problem related to the topic and, on a side note, I noticed that VS 2015 performs significantly better when it comes to debugging ASP applications. 
Furthermore, using Team Foundation Server along with these projects also worked fine.